# Gnuplot plot 3D data on xy graph with contours

Tags: plot, label, gnuplot, contour

I try to plot 3D data on a xy plane graph with contours. I manage to get the color map but I have few issues.
My data are in 3 columns (see code below) with space between each row.

```
0.000000000 0.897777778 0.000000000  
0.000000000 0.906666667 0.000000000  
0.000000000 0.915555556 0.000000000  
0.000000000 0.924444444 0.000000000  
0.000000000 0.933333333 0.000000000  
0.000000000 0.942222222 0.000000000  
0.000000000 0.951111111 0.000000000  
0.000000000 0.960000000 0.000000000  
0.000000000 0.968888889 0.000000000  
0.000000000 0.977777778 0.000000000  
0.000000000 0.986666667 0.000000000  
0.000000000 0.995555556 0.000000000  

0.111111111 0.453837597 0.008893913  
0.111111111 0.462736374 0.009285188  
0.111111111 0.471635150 0.009686812  
0.111111111 0.480533927 0.010098938  
0.111111111 0.489432703 0.010521720  
0.111111111 0.498331479 0.010955318  
0.111111111 0.507230256 0.011399894  
0.111111111 0.516129032 0.011855617
```

My code is the following:

```
set terminal postscript eps color enhanced "Helvetica" 14
set output 'phiCH_TpFR.eps'
set contour base
set style textbox opaque noborder
unset surface
set style textbox opaque noborder
set cntrparam level discrete 0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3
set cntrparam bspline
set isosamples 250, 250
set view map
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0.55:0.95]
set cbrange [0:4]
set dgrid3d 50,50,50 gauss .005, .035

set table "contour_CH.txt"
splot "data_sensibilite_correlation_Tpfr_CH"
unset table

unset contour
set surface
set table "dgrid_CH.txt"
splot "data_sensibilite_correlation_Tpfr_CH"
unset table

reset
set pm3d map
unset key
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0.55:0.95]
set cbrange [0:4]
set xlabel "{/Symbol e}_{/Symbol q} [%]"
set ylabel "T_b / T_{w hs}"
set cblabel "{/Symbol e}_{{/Symbol F} hs} [%]"
splot 'dgrid_CH.txt' w pm3d, 'contour_CH.txt' w l lc rgb "black", 'contour_CH.txt' every 10 w labels
```

And I get the following graph:
[image]

My issues are the following:

1. I did not manage to get the labels of the contour plot. What can I do to solve this ? I notice that in the file "contour_CH.txt" not all the contours have labels. I do not know if this is the cause of my problem.

   # Contour 1, label:      2.5
   7.29125  0.900642  2.5
   7.26953  0.901372  2.5
   7.24415  0.902123  2.5
   7.21428  0.902917  2.5
   7.18137  0.903743  2.5
   7.14745  0.904582  2.5
   7.11456  0.905415  2.5
   7.08473  0.906223  2.5
   7.05941  0.906997  2.5
   7.03775  0.907755  2.5
   7.0183  0.908527  2.5
   6.99961  0.909341  2.5
   ....

   # Contour 2, label:
   9.88889  0.816038  2.5
   9.80771  0.818407  2.5
   9.75248  0.820019  2.5
   ....
2. There is a white space between my axis and the color map. I do not understand why since my data are wider than the plot range.

Thank you in advance for your answer,

Martin

Comment: Please post data as text, not as image.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63788443/7295599

Comment: What are your min/max x and y values? I would guess that gnuplot automatically tries to make "nice" tic numbers at the end, here: xrange[0:10] and yrange[0.55:0.95]. If you don't want white space set the range values to exaclty your min/max values for x and y.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I checked your link but I do not manage to make it works. Copy/paste the proposed the code and replace by my data lead to a warning message : "warning: Cannot contour non grid data. Please use "set dgrid3d"."

Comment: Concerning the min/max x and y values, all isocurves of my dgrid_CH.txt files contains values below 0.5 and above 0.99 for the y axis. For the x axis, it is indeed 9.89 and not 10.

Comment: hmmm, difficult without having some "real" data to reproduce. Could you either minimize your data while still reproducing your result or make the full data available? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Here is the link to the data : docs.google.com/document/d/…. Before, I applied an algorithm to my data to remove out of scope values. This was the cause of the error about non grid data. The link above gives access to the non full data (which do not require the use of dgrid3d). However, I still do not manage to plot my data with contours.

Comment: uncomplete link...

Comment: Sorry, it was a miss click. Here is the link to the data : https://docs.google.com/document/d/15OVz1x02pR-tbWdPx0auCCNdIl3Ylw_sh3DiK8Wh6xs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry, requires Google account... I don't have and don't want one.

Comment: How can I send it to you otherwise ?

Comment: Here is the link to the data: https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=bdc1c84d-426c-4e8a-a2c6-c9e246a26bcc

Answer (score 0):

If you check `help contour`, it will tell you that contour is only available for `splot`. However, you can splot the data into a table and use this contour table for `plot`. The first block (separated by two empty lines) of `$Contour` contains the data and the following block contains the contour line data separated by single empty lines. You can address the latter via `index 1::1`.

I would try something like this as a starting point, certainly room for improvements: (tested with gnuplot 5.0.0 and 5.2.8). Apparently, your data is skewed.

**Code:**

```
### plot heatmap with contour lines
reset session

FILE = "Martin7data.dat"

set contour
set cntrparam level discrete 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3
set table $Contour
    splot FILE u 1:2:3
unset table

set style textbox opaque
unset key

set view
plot FILE u 1:2:3 w image, \
     $Contour u 1:2 index 1::1 w l lc "red", \
     '' u 1:2:3 index 1::1 every ::0::0 w labels boxed
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much theozh. Indeed my data are skewed but the range that interest me is: for xrange [0:10] and yrange[0.55,0.95]. When I put these range limitation the color map is extended outside the axis limits. How can I force the graph to be drawn only inside the axis limit ?